# Can't overcome an emptystring

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, dom

You'll see rapidly I'm no programmer and just stepping in at the last minute to help a friend. Using XML files, we're trying to overcome an empty string.

**Here's my code:**

```
{ 
  document.write("<tr><td align='left'><font color='#333333'>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Party")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</font></td><td align='left'>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Vote")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td align='right'>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Total")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td></tr>");
}
```

Because there isn't always a "Party" associated with a "Name", the script stops when the element is empty.

In this example, how can I overcome it?

**I've tried this, without any luck:**

```
daNode = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Party")[0];

if (daNode.childNodes.length) {
  da = daNode.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
} else {
  da = "none"
}
```

Thanks!

***Edit to add XML from comments:***

```
<xml>
  <Election>
    <Candidates>
      <Candidate> 
        <Name>Max</Name>
        <Party>Action</Party>
        <Vote>42 votes</Vote> 
        <Total>10 %</Total> 
      </Candidate>
      <Candidate> 
        <Name>John</Name>
        <Party></Party>
        <Vote>82 votes</Vote>
        <Total>20 %</Total>
      </Candidate> 
      <Candidate> 
        <Name>Simon</Name>
        <Party>Action</Party>
        <Vote>1 vote</Vote>
        <Total>1 %</Total>
      </Candidate>
    </Candidates>
  </Election>
</xml>
```

Comment: I believe it's JavaScript...?

Comment: could you show some XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas, I found the issue. Text nodes (the actual content of a tag) is considered a child of the tag, so your `<Party>` tag which has no text node is returning null at `.childNodes[0]` and therefore an error at `.nodeValue`. Here's a fix:

```
{ 
   var partyNode = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Party")[0];
   var party = partyNode.firstChild ? partyNode.firstChild.nodeValue : "none";

   document.write("<tr><td align='left'><font color='#333333'>");
   document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
   document.write(party);  
   document.write("</font></td><td align='left'>");
   document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Vote")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
   document.write("</td><td align='right'>");
   document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Total")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
   document.write("</td></tr>");
}
```

Comment: Is it bad practice to assume `0` is falsey? Trying to refresh myself on this one. If so, wouldn't `if (daNode > 0) {` be a better check? Since outside this area, `daNode.length` could be anything. Correct me if I'm wrong! I'm a js newb. :)

Comment: No it's safe in this situation. length is either 0 or greater than zero. `if (length)` is the same as `if (length > 0)`

Comment: Hmmm... Still not working. Unless I have this part at the wrong place...?

Comment: See my update, it should work. Please note that `document.write` is bad practice, you should be using DOM manipulation methods like `document.createElement()` and `Node.appendChild()`.

Comment: Yes, I've learned that about [document.write] tonight... But, after patching the update, every data cell of the table has "null" written in them?

Comment: Oh fantastic. Thank you. I wouldn't of figured the [var], this is all too new. 
In the other code, I was trying to add ", "+ in between "Name" and "Party". In this set, where would I enter it? If i put it here: document.write(", "+ party); there's comma everywhere and not just where there's actually a party.

Comment: I was mumbling over this:
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write(", "+ x[i].getElementsByTagName("Party")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

Comment: in my answer, you can use: `document.write(", " + party)`

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. But it does put a comma to every "Candidate", not only the ones with a party tag. Is there a way to only put a comma after the names associated with a party in your answer?

Comment: `document.write(party == "none" ? "" : ", " + party)`